# perl alternative for sed to split multiple |

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I was able to accomplish this in sed command, but could not get it working in perl. Would like to add spaces between pipe characters that are close together without any spaces or alphanumerics.

```
input           ==>  a|123|##||||
expected output ==>  a|123|##| | | |
```

This `sed` command works fine:

```
echo "a|123|##||||" | sed 's/\([^[:blank:][:alnum:]]\)|/\1 | /g'
```

output for above command ==> `a|123|## | | | |`

In perl, I could not get it working

```
echo "a|123|##||||" | perl -pe 's/\([^[:blank:][:alnum:]]\)|/\1 | /g'
```

with output for above command

```
| a | | | 1 | 2 | 3 | | | # | # | | | | | | | | |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add space only between those `|` that come next to each other

```
echo "a|123|##||||" | perl -pe's/\|(?=\|)/\| /g'
```

I use a lookahead in order to be able to detect consecutive (and overlapping!) pairs, with more than two `|` strung together: Only the first one in a match is consumed so the second one stays there for the next match, in case there is yet another after it (again asserted with the lookahead).

Answer (score 2):

Another way using both lookahead and lookbehind.

```
$ echo "a|123|##||||" | perl -pe's/(?<=\|)(?=\|)/ /g '
a|123|##| | | |

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Perl syntax would be:

```
echo "a|123|##||||" | perl -pe 's/([^\s\w])\|/$1 | /g'
```

- Pipe character must be escaped
- $1 is used for 1st group match